Nearest neighbor for list of arrays
`I have a list of arrays like this (in x, y coordinates):
coordinates= array([[ 300, 2300],
      [ 670, 2360],
      [ 400, 2300]]), array([[1500, 1960],
      [1620, 2200],
      [1505, 1975]]), array([[ 980, 1965],
      [1060, 2240],
      [1100, 2250],
      [ 980, 1975]]), array([[ 565, 1940],
      [ 680, 2180],
      [ 570, 1945]])]

I want the arrays to be sorted by the nearest neighbor. So, the last coordinate of the first array should be close to the first coordinate of the next array and so forth.
I extracted all of the first and last coordinates and put them in two lists using python numpy. Then tried to use sklearn.neighbors NearestNeighbors, but it didn't work.`
expected output:
coordinates= array([[ 300, 2300],
      [ 670, 2360],
      [ 400, 2300]]), array([[ 565, 1940],
      [ 680, 2180],
      [ 570, 1945]]), array([[ 980, 1965],
      [1060, 2240],
      [1100, 2250],
      [ 980, 1975]]), array([[1500, 1960],
      [1620, 2200],
      [1505, 1975]])]


Please provide expected output.

Is this what you expect?

I posted the expected output

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This looks like a traveling_salesman_problem. Compute the pairwise distance between all nodes, make the self distance NaN/Inf, then get the shortest path:
from numpy import array
import networkx as nx

coordinates= [array([[ 300, 2300],
                     [ 670, 2360],
                     [ 400, 2300]]),
              array([[1500, 1960],
                     [1620, 2200],
                     [1505, 1975]]),
              array([[ 980, 1965],
                     [1060, 2240],
                     [1100, 2250],
                     [ 980, 1975]]),
              array([[ 565, 1940],
                     [ 680, 2180],
                     [ 570, 1945]])]

# extract starts and ends
starts = np.vstack([a[0]  for a in coordinates])
ends   = np.vstack([a[-1] for a in coordinates])

# compute pairwise distances, except self
dist = np.sqrt(((starts[:, None] - ends)**2).sum(-1))
np.fill_diagonal(dist, np.nan)

# build the graph
G = nx.from_numpy_array(np.round(dist, 1), create_using=nx.DiGraph)
G.remove_edges_from(nx.selfloop_edges(G))

# find shortest path (NB. cycle could be False)
path = nx.approximation.traveling_salesman_problem(G, cycle=True)
# [1, 0, 3, 2, 1]

out = [coordinates[i] for i in path[1:]]

If you don't necessarily want a cycle, use cycle=False and out = [coordinates[i] for i in path].
Output:
[array([[ 300, 2300],
        [ 670, 2360],
        [ 400, 2300]]),
 array([[ 565, 1940],
        [ 680, 2180],
        [ 570, 1945]]),
 array([[ 980, 1965],
        [1060, 2240],
        [1100, 2250],
        [ 980, 1975]]),
 array([[1500, 1960],
        [1620, 2200],
        [1505, 1975]])]

Intermediate dist:
array([[          nan, 1248.05849222,  753.67433285,  446.01008957],
       [1151.34703717,           nan,  520.21630117,  930.12095988],
       [ 669.79474468,  525.09522946,           nan,  410.48751504],
       [ 396.01136347,  940.65137006,  416.47328846,           nan]])

Graph (with distances as edge labels and the shortest path in red):


Use BallTree : from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
BallTree excels at finding nearest neighbors in high-dimensional data,
especially when combined with a technique like the remaining_mask,
to focus on relevant segments.
It utilizes a tree-based structure that allows for faster searches.
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

coordinates = [
    np.array([[300, 2300],
              [670, 2360],
              [400, 2300]]),
    np.array([[1500, 1960],
              [1620, 2200],
              [1505, 1975]]),
    np.array([[980, 1965],
              [1060, 2240],
              [1100, 2250],
              [980, 1975]]),
    np.array([[565, 1940],
              [680, 2180],
              [570, 1945]])
]

# Extract first and last coordinates
first_coords = np.array([arr[0] for arr in coordinates])
last_coords = np.array([arr[-1] for arr in coordinates])

#print("First coordinates:\n", first_coords)
'''
First coordinates:
 [[ 300 2300]
 [1500 1960]
 [ 980 1965]
 [ 565 1940]]
'''
#print("Last coordinates:\n", last_coords)

'''
Last coordinates:
 [[ 400 2300]
 [1505 1975]
 [ 980 1975]
 [ 570 1945]]
'''
# Build a BallTree for first coordinates
tree = BallTree(first_coords)

# Initialize the sorted list with the first coordinate set
sorted_indices = [0]
'''
np.ones fills the mask with all elements set to True.
This signifies that initially, all segments are considered "unused" 
and eligible to be chosen as the next closest neighbor in the loop.
the remaining_mask acts as a dynamic flag that tracks the used segments. 
Setting elements to False prevents the algorithm from revisiting previously 
chosen segments as potential neighbors.
'''
remaining_mask = np.ones(len(coordinates), dtype=bool)
'''
This indicates that the first segment has already been chosen as the starting point 
and is no longer considered "available"
for further comparisons in subsequent iterations of the loop.
'''

remaining_mask[0] = False  # Mark the first segment as used
current_index = 0 

# Find closest neighbors and filter with mask in one step
while remaining_mask.any():
    # Query BallTree for k=len(coordinates) to get all distances
    distances, indices = tree.query(last_coords[current_index].reshape(1, -1), k=len(coordinates))
    #print(f"Querying BallTree for last_coords[{current_index}]:", last_coords[current_index])
    
    # Combine mask and indices for efficient filtering
    flat_indices = indices.ravel()

    filtered_mask = remaining_mask[flat_indices]

    filtered_indices = flat_indices[filtered_mask]

    closest_index = filtered_indices[0]

    # Update sorted indices, current index, and mask
    sorted_indices.append(closest_index)
    current_index = closest_index
    remaining_mask[closest_index] = False

# Use the sorted indices to arrange the coordinates
sorted_coordinates = [coordinates[i] for i in sorted_indices]

print("Sorted coordinates:\n", sorted_coordinates)
'''
Sorted coordinates:
[array([[ 300, 2300],
       [ 670, 2360],
       [ 400, 2300]]), 
array([[ 565, 1940],
       [ 680, 2180],
       [ 570, 1945]]), 
array([[ 980, 1965],
       [1060, 2240],
       [1100, 2250],
       [ 980, 1975]]), 
array([[1500, 1960],
       [1620, 2200],
       [1505, 1975]])]

'''

